# App crashes when i and ranking to my query string

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
"SELECT * FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES;
```

this code works but i want to have ranking column so i added updated it to this

```
  String queryString = "SELECT *,RANK () OVER" + "( " +"ORDER BY " + STUDENT_NAME_COL + " )" +  SP + " FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES ;
```

it gives me this error code under the opening bracket <compound,>,FROM,GROUP,ORDER.WHERE,COMMA or SEMMICOLON expected, got "("
and app crashes;

this is how it views[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCzDT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the version of SQLite in the device that you run the app is lower than 3.25.0 so it does not support window functions.

You can emulate `RANK()` with a correlated subquery:

```
String queryString = 
    "SELECT s1.*, " + 
    "(SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES + " AS s2 WHERE s2." + STUDENT_NAME_COL + " < s1."  +  STUDENT_NAME_COL + ") AS SP "+
    "FROM " + STUDENT_TABLES + " AS s1";
```

Comment: works perfectly. but in reverse. dont know much about sub queries. could you show me where i can sort by student name in decending order.

Comment: works perfectly. but in reverse. dont know much about sub queries. could you show me where i can sort by student name in descending order.

Comment: @IsaiahDonkor what do you mean *in reverse*? In your code you don't rank in descending order.

Comment: .I mean it does the opposite of what i want. The student that should come first comes last. so applying the the DSC will help me but i dont know how. help me please. Then later recommnd where i can learn the concept

Comment: @IsaiahDonkor What do you mean *opposite of what you want*? Your question has nothing to do with sorting the rows of the query. All you mention is that a query that uses the window function RANK() (in ascending and not descending order) is crashing your app and nothing more. In SO you get answers for the questions as you post them and the comments section is not the place to ask new questions. Here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/ you can find more about sorting.